# How to use pivot in sql into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody help me with SQL using pivot?

For example I have a list shown below with 1 column:

[image]

and I want the result to become this:

[image]

I tried pivot but I only got 1 row.. I just need multiple rows.

Comment: why would you want such output , just out of curiosity what's the real life use case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions.  In your case, you have a sequence with no gaps, so you can just use modulo arithmetic:

```
    select max(case when units % 10 = 1 then units end),
           max(case when units % 10 = 2 then units end),
           . . .
           max(case when units % 10 = 0 then units end)
    from t
    group by ceiling(units / 10.0);
```